# Upstart: How to respond to startup of a service, thats not part of Upstart?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, upstart

I'm running Ubuntu server and playing around with Upstart. I have installed PostgreSQL database server which **doesn't use** Upstart system, however im also writting an Upstart script that starts another process which depends on the PostgreSQL server to be up and running. How do i setup my Upstart conf file to run when the PostgreSQL will already be running since its not part of the Upstart?

Heres my simple script so far:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec /spatial/server_init.sh
```

Comment: Okay, i think i ll try writting the Postgresql job in Upstart, i found this useful link: http://bradleyayers.blogspot.com/2011/10/upstart-job-for-postgresql-91-on-ubuntu.html